# How do I change the color of a UITableView row when it is selected?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, select, background

I've looked around for answers to this but have yet to find one that works. All I want to do is to be able to change the background color, or image of the UITableView row that I select.

I am used to just transitioning views when you I select a row, but this time I want to be able to change that rows properties. I know which row I want to change, with indexPath.row, but I don't know how I would go about changing how the row looks because the cellForRowAtIndexPath method has already been called!

What can I do to change the color?

Comment: Do you reload the tableview with `[tableView reloadData]`?

Comment: Well, I imagine that would work, but then I'd somehow have to pass in the index value that I selected...it could work but it seems like there should be a more elegant solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //First you get the cell you want to change
    UITableViewCell* theCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Then you change the properties (label, text, color etc..) in your case, the background color
    theCell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    //Deselect the cell so you can see the color change

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Just make sure you consider this color change when you recycle cells.

If you need more info just post a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Set a variable to the active row:

```
int activeRow;
```

When building the cell check if it's the active row and set the background color

```
if (indexPath.row == activeRow) {
    cell.setMyBackgroundColor = [UIColor myCoolColor];
} else {
    cell.setMyBackgroundColor = [UIColor normalColor];
}
```

Don't forget to set the background color even on the normal case, since they are reused.

On selection (or whenever is appropriate), update that particular cell:

```
NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:YES];
```

I would suggest this method as there may be events that cause the refresh of your table, and you may not want to lose the background color. This could happen if you just set the cell directly on selection.