# Change Color of UI Table View's Specific row

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to change color dynamically if any new row is added to UITableView.If any row is selected Once than change color of that row. **How Can I accomplish this task..?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098108/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-a-uitableview-row-when-it-is-selected)

Comment: this was not so useful answer thats why with some additional functionality i asked

Answer (score 1):

You Can do like this,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //First you get the cell you want to change
    UITableViewCell* theCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Then you change the properties (label, text, color etc..) in your case, the background color
    theCell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    //Deselect the cell so you can see the color change

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Exact copy paste of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098108/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-a-uitableview-row-when-it-is-selected

Comment: This is the same thing @gulliver007 said

Comment: if you do so than color changed for a while.not so helfull

Answer (score 0):

You'll have reload the `UITableView` every time you need to change the color of your row. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function you'll have setup a switch case:

```
switch(indexpath.row)
{
    case 1:
          //set the cell background color.
    .
    .
    .
    default :
          // color u want by default
}
```

If you want to change the color of particular row which is selected by user. Then you'll have to save the row number in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` change the background color of that particular row.

```
if(indexpath.row == selectedRow)
{
   //set this color
}
else
{
   //set another color
}
```

Comment: since you haven't check the answer that was not helpful. thats why.

Comment: @user1936466 i didn't get you.